# Updating the correct fields in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have few fields in a form say

```
<form action="?code='.$order_id.'" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="'.$row_order['length'].'">
    <input type="text" name="breadth" placeholder="'.$row_order['breadth'].'">
    <input type="text" name="width" placeholder="'.$row_order['width'].'">
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

I retrieve the value of length, breadth and width from database and show it through a placeholder. Now I want if the user enters some value say in length then only length field in DB to be affected others being intact.

Now if I put the value of length as 50 and "Save" it then it shows length=50, breadth=0 and width=0 even if I had breadth=40 and width=30 before updating.

Comment: use value="" not placeholder=""

Answer (score 2):

Instead of placeholder use value in input tag

```
<form action="?code='.$order_id.'" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="length" value="'.$row_order['length'].'"> 
<input type="text" name="breadth" value="'.$row_order['breadth'].'"> 
<input type="text" name="width" value="'.$row_order['width'].'"> 
 <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"> </form>
```